# Date Calculator in Acrobat

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I am making a fillable PDF form in Acrobat, and in one field I require a piece of script to calculate days between the dates in two other fields. Basically one field will be start date, one field will be end date and the calculation field will count the days, including the both the start and end day (inclusive). ie: Start: 1/11/14 End: 3/11/14 Days: 3

The more tricky (I think) bit is that I need it to only count business days (not Saturday or Sunday) and also to disregard public holidays from the count. For the holidays part, I will need the ability to input a list of dates manually into the script, so that it can be updated year on year.

I have already attempted this myself by reading endless posts etc, and managed to get a correct day count, but then fell down on the weekend and holiday hurdle.

Anyone who could help me out by writing a script would be doing me a massive favour.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var sDate1=this.getField("First Day of Leave").value;
var sDate2=this.getField("Last Day of Leave").value;
var oDate1 = util.scand("dd/mm/yy", sDate1);
var oDate2 = util.scand("dd/mm/yy", sDate2);
var nDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var eDays=Math.abs(oDate1-oDate2)/nDay;
var addDay = 1;
event.value=Math.round(eDays + addDay)+" days";
```

Comment: Post what you have so far

Comment: Take a look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and the plugin for holidays [Here](https://gist.github.com/jrhames/5200024)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for complete code.

Comment: Added the script I have so far to my original post @APAD1

Comment: Posted where I'm up to so far, sorry @Mathletics

Answer (score 0):

If you need the exact number of days, and take care of the holidays, you will end up enumerating every day from begin date to end date and evaluate whether it is a weekend day (getDay() is 0 (Sunday) or 6 (Saturday). For the holidays, however, you will to check with a list of holidays you/your organization counts.